# Unity Dash Application search results - some icons appear as blank page icons

Tags: icons, unity-dash, search

Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on Dell E6420 (Sandybridge graphics)

Open Unity Dash search

My filters are set only on "Applications" and "Files & Folders"

I type : Software

The results are good but some icons appear as blank page icons (document?)

Example  Applications : "Ubuntu Software Centre"  and "Software & Updates"

"Software Updater" has the correct application icon.

(The blank page icon look like a blank page with the top right corner folded.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually resolved itself when I restarted the laptop the next day.

There had been an update that did not require a restart, may be that was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Install unity-tweak-tool and select a different icon theme.  Choosing the "Default" theme should resolve the issue.

There are some themes that don't have any configured icons.

```
$ sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

---

Actually upon further investigation I'm noticing that the "Default" icon configuration may be missing some icons in some of the default themes. These are a few that are more likely to be complete:

- Humanity
- Humanity-dark
- Ubuntu-icon-theme
- Ubuntu-mono-dark